# Update text in Quill JS using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi guys Ive created a text editor using Quill JS, and when I press a button I would like the editor to be populated with data from my database.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');

    function getInfo(){
        global $pdo;
        $query ="SELECT * FROM myDatabase WHERE ID =1 ";
        $statement = $pdo ->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $Info = $statement->fetchAll();
        $Text = $Info[0]['Text'];
        $TextJson = json_encode($Text, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        return $TextJson;
    }

    echo $TextJson();
?>

<script>
    var Text = "bananas";
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {theme: 'snow'});
        quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(Text);
    function loadText(){
        var fetchText = $.get( "fetchText.php", function(data) {
            //data = 'apples'
            Text = data;
        });
    } 
</script>

<html> <button onclick="loadText()"> load the text </button> </html>
```

I would like to make it so when the button is clicked, the text in the Quill changes to 'apples' ( the data from the db), at the moment nothing happens.

Any help would be great cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't `echo $TextJson();` actually be `echo getInfo();` instead?

Comment: And then (only guessing here) you probably have to do this again inside the ajax return: `quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(Text);`... so that quill updates itself? (i've not used quill, so unsure... but it sounds logical lol)